# Backbone and composite models in REST api - is it possible?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing, backbone-model

First I apologize as I am not sure the question title accurately describes what I am trying to do. I love/hate backbones REST api structure, but I am trying add on to it a bit and support a 'graph' of relationships between the models.

So the simplest end point is something like:

```
/machines/:id
```

or

```
/projects
```

But I want to take it a step further and show the 'graph' of relationships:

```
/machines/:machine_id/projects
```

or

```
/machines/:machine_id/projects/:project_id
```

I am trying to think of the best approach to take and wonder if anyone has any experience they would care to share in this area. As it stands now I have defined models for `machines` and `projects` and the non-relational end points work. I guess my next step would be to create a fictitious composite model `MachinesProjects` - but not sure how I would go about hacking up the model's url concatenation to respond to the different attributes that represent ids. Further, I'm hoping there's something better as I really don't want to explicitly define a model for every arc in the graph between model types.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like the following?

```
var Machine = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot:"/machines"
});

var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot:"/projects"
});

var MachineProject = Project.extend({
  url: function() {
    return this.machine.url() + Project.prototype.url.call(this);
  },
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.machine = options.machine;
  }
});
```